# How it's possible I got this crash report? My app wanted to make a call?

Tags: android

I have an app in the Market that got quite popular (~30k downloads, ~22k active installs). I'm using ACRA which is sending me crash reports, so I can find bugs faster. I've seen a lot of strange logs, but all of the reported errors were *understandable* - that means, I always had an idea what could lead to a crash.

Until now. I've got two crash reports with this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x14200000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{40ac3378 23747:org.my.application.package/10088} (pid=23747, uid=10088) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
....
```

My application has nothing to do with calls. It's just downloading some data from the internet and displays it to the user. How it's possible, that my application suddenly wanted to call someone?

It may be relevant, that these two crash reports came from modified android ROM called "cyanogendefy".

EDIT:

None of the TextViews that contain the data has autoLink enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If the data that you downloaded and then displayed had a phone number in it, the user might then click on the phone number and thus try to launch the dialer. It's tough to say for sure though. How are you displaying that data?

Comment: Good point - but I'm quite sure it's not the case. Even if the data would contain a phone number (it's theoretically possible), the text is displayed only in TextViews - none of them has "autoLink" set.

I've just checked, by setting the hardcoded text with a phone number and it's not clickable. Although, maybe this modded android enables "autoLink" on all TextViews.